# How to print json api data in reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I'm fetching json api details through `GET` request and trying to print it. Getting an error:

Error in the console is `Uncaught ReferenceError: allUsers is not defined`

```js
    const Dashboard = ({status, juser}) => {
const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = React.useState([]);
const id = juser.actable_id;
console.log(id); //getting id here as 1
const getAllusers = () => {
    axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3001/user/${id}`, { withCredentials: true })
        .then((response) => {
           console.log(response.data);
            setAllUsers(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(" error", error);
        });
};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getAllusers();
  }, []);

{allUsers.map((job_seeker, index) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{job_seeker.name}</p>
        </div>
    );
})}
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I'm new to react. Any help is appreciatable.

Comment: I think you really need to read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable) carefully. Your setter function is `allUsers` and you're trying to use it as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);
```

the state is where your data is located and setState is function to reset the state from anywhere,

so on your code,

```
const [jobseekers, allUsers] = React.useState([]); // change string to array
```

jobseekers is the variable where your data is located and allUsers is the function to store data into state.

set data to state using **allUsers** function,

```
const getAllusers = () => {
    axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3001/user/${id}`, { withCredentials: true })
        .then((response) => {
            allUsers(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(" error", error);
        });
};
```

and map from **jobseekers**

```
{jobseekers.map((job_seeker, index) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{job_seeker.name}</p>
        </div>
    );
})}
```

Also I would suggest to rename your **state** and **setState** as,

```
const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = React.useState([]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohiuddin Khan, but have a error like this "Duplicate declaration "allUsers" " afer adding this const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = React.useState([]);

Comment: You have to remove the initial hook you used `const [jobseekers, allUsers] = React.useState('')`

Comment: @Mohiuddin Khan thanks a lot for helping me. great thanks for sharing some readings related to this. i. updated my anwer based on your corrections.

Comment: @SreRoR glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass the value of response to allUsers, instead, you just created a new variable. So change

```
   const allUsers = response.data;
```

to:

```
   allUsers(response.data)
```

Besides, you can also improve the way that you have used `useState`. You have initialized it as an empty string while you'll probably store an array from response in `jobseekers`. So, initialize it as an empty array.

```
const [jobseekers, allUsers] = React.useState([]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help. Kindly forgive @ali sasani accepting above answer . He replied first. Don't think bad. even you also answered the same and correct one